# Mutaion in grapgql by Axios React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, hasura

I was trying to mutation in graphQL by using Hasura's API console. I checked in Hasura it's properly worked there. But when I was trying to add in react code it gives an error.

**Code:**

```
Axios.post("http://domain.herokuapp.com/v1/graphql", {
      query: `
mutation createCompanyBusiness {
 
        insert_appcompany(objects: { 
          fullname: "Company Full Name 344",  
          contact: "{{\"Tel\", 01}, {Email, email@test.com}}",  
          billing_floor_flat_house_no: "floor 14, house 6",  
          last_update_by: 112,  
          create_by: 112, 
      
          privacy: true,  
          app_property: { 
            data: { 
              property_name: "Niketon House",  
              building_number: "22C",  
              last_update_by: 122,  
              create_by: 122,  
              app_street: { 
                data: { 
                  street_name:  
                  "Long Street",  
                  district_suburb_county_city: "New City",  
                  town_city: "New Town",  
                  country: "Singapore",  
                  last_update_by: 122,  
                  create_by: 122 
                } 
              } 
            } 
          } 
        }) { 
          returning { 
            appcompany_id 
          } 
        } 
      } 
      
      
      `,
    })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

**Output Log:**

[image: Output Log Screenshot]

Comment: use variables, test in playground ... and, of course, use search

Comment: `contact: "{{\"Tel\", 01}, {Email, email@test.com}}"` - this looks suspicious. It must be text or json?